# PencilKit - ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage when uploading app to AppStoreConnect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-pencil, pencilkit

I tried weak linking PencilKit in 3 different ways:

1. Via target > Frameworks > Add PencilKit > Do Not Embed
2. By weak linking using "-weak_framework PencilKit" in other linker flags
3. By linking using "-framework PencilKit" in other linker flags

Each build was rejected using ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage.

The project is in Objective-C. I also re-wrote the view controller that uses PencilKit into Swift and got the same error since that also bridges to ObjC land.

Has anyone successfully uploaded an archive to AppStoreConnect that is also linked with PencilKit and has a lower deployment target than iOS 13.0?

Answer (score 1):

They just fixed it in Xcode 11.1 GM, you can upload also to previous versions older than iOS 13 (without support of course).

Comment: Yup. Fixed in 11.1 GM

Answer (score 0):

[PencilKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit) is a new framework available for iOS 13.0 and newer. As iOS 13 is not released yet, you cannot publish app using it yet!

So set your app deployment target as 13.0 and wait for iOS 13 to be released.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted to publish the app. But iOS 13 API's are available to users on TestFlight, so it should be possible to upload the app with PencilKit for TestFlight users on iOS 13 when the deployment target is lower than 13.0. Other's are also facing this issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/376096#376096

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here..., think I got it working now. Because I did not received a mail from Apple, and the build is showing.... I upgraded webview to @4.1.1

Here is my list:

```
   cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1
```